# react native run android faces 'NativeModules' exception

Tags: android, react-native

When i go to deploy my android device by typing 'react-native run-android' at MAC terminal , it builds everything smoothly and goes to the following exception page.

[image]

After deploying the following modules as below :

[image]

Would you please tell me what to focus or are there any methods to clean and rebuild the whole Android project rendered ?

Comment: Are you linting your code. Looks like an error that may be in your source code. Trying running a fresh build see what happens

Comment: What is lintjng ?

Comment: Like eslinting... module for showing errors and possibly warning in your code before final build.

Comment: Where can we see it ? I only see NDK warning in the terminal console.